# How to Create Partially Stacked Bar Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to make a partially stacked bar plot of *n* elements where *n* - 1 elements are stacked, and the remaining element is another bar adjacent to the stacked bars of equal width. The adjacent bar element is plotted on a secondary y-axis and is typically a percentage, plotted between 0 and 1.

The solution that I am currently using is able to represent the data fine, but I'm curious to know how I could achieve the desired result of an equal width single bar next to a stacked bar.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

mylabels=list('BCD')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,11,size=(5,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['A'] = list('abcde')
df['D'] = np.random.rand(5,1)

ax = df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(['D'])].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, x='A', figsize=(15,7))
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.bar(df.A,df.D, color='g', width=.1)
ax2.set_ylim(0,1)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='g')
handles.append(green_patch)
ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=mylabels)
ax.set_xlabel('')
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try passing `align='edge'` and `width` to control the relative position of the bars:

```
ax = df.drop('D', axis=1).plot.bar(x='A', stacked=True, align='edge', width=-0.4)
ax1=ax.twinx()


df.plot.bar(x='A',y='D', width=0.4, align='edge', ax=ax1, color='C2')

# manually set the limit so the left most bar isn't cropped
ax.set_xlim(-0.5)


# handle the legends
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
h, l = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles + h, labels=mylabels+l)
ax1.legend().remove()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Neat!  I was going to use the position parameter and pass postion=1 and position=0.

Comment: @ScottBoston yeah, `position` is neat too.

Comment: Would position work for more than one adjacent bar? (i.e. one stacked and two adjacent)

Comment: Same with edge, it’s unlikely to work. You need to manually shift the bars when you have more than two bars at one tick.

Comment: I see, manually shifting the bars would be setting them to new x values adjusted to be flush with the neighboring bars? thx @QuangHoang